# How to Get Excel 64bits path from regedit under windows7 64 bits?

Tags: excel, regedit

Could anyone who has Excel64bits installed on his win7/64bits tell me how to get ecel path from the regedit?

**I have Excel 32bits installed on my PC and i am looking for the path for a 64bit version which i don't have**

Comment: This question should probably be moved to superuser board

Answer (score 0):

Press `WINDOWS+R`, write `regedit`, hit `ENTER`and press `CTRL+F` then type "excel" you can find registry element with value like this `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE"`

Comment: I have Excel 32bits installed on my PC and i am looking for the path for a 64bit version which i don't have.

Comment: Look at my answer, this path is for excel x64: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE`

Comment: Could you please sent me the path from Regedit it should be something similiar to the followin path : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\CLSID\...\LocalServer

Comment: For example: `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CLasses\Excel.Addin\shell\Open\Command`

Comment: Or check this link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772637(v=ws.10).aspx